# How to do/workaround a conditional join in python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, conditional-statements

I am trying to calculate time-based aggregations in Pandas based on date values stored in a separate tables.

The top of the first table `table_a` looks like this:

```
    COMPANY_ID  DATE            MEASURE
    1   2010-01-01 00:00:00     10
    1   2010-01-02 00:00:00     10
    1   2010-01-03 00:00:00     10
    1   2010-01-04 00:00:00     10
    1   2010-01-05 00:00:00     10
```

Here is the code to create the table:

```
    table_a = pd.concat(\
    [pd.DataFrame({'DATE': pd.date_range("01/01/2010", "12/31/2010", freq="D"),\
    'COMPANY_ID': 1 , 'MEASURE': 10}),\
    pd.DataFrame({'DATE': pd.date_range("01/01/2010", "12/31/2010", freq="D"),\
    'COMPANY_ID': 2 , 'MEASURE': 10})])
```

The second table, `table_b`, looks like this:

```
        COMPANY     END_DATE
        1   2010-03-01 00:00:00
        1   2010-06-02 00:00:00
        2   2010-03-01 00:00:00
        2   2010-06-02 00:00:00
```

and the code to create it is:

```
    table_b = pd.DataFrame({'END_DATE':pd.to_datetime(['03/01/2010','06/02/2010','03/01/2010','06/02/2010']),\
                    'COMPANY':(1,1,2,2)})
```

I want to be able to get the sum of the 'measure' column for each 'COMPANY_ID' for each 30-day period prior to the 'END_DATE' in `table_b`.

This is (I think) the SQL equivalent:

```
 select
       b.COMPANY_ID,
       b.DATE
       sum(a.MEASURE) AS MEASURE_TO_END_DATE
 from table_a a, table_b b
 where a.COMPANY = b.COMPANY and
       a.DATE < b.DATE and
       a.DATE > b.DATE - 30  
 group by b.COMPANY;
```

Comment: Does `end_date` in table_b every have overlapping windows; e.g., could company 1 have an end_date's of 2010-03-01 and 2010-03-15.

Comment: Hi @KarlD yes potentially.

Comment: `table_b` seems inefficient, is it just the Cartesian crossproduct of all (or most) COMPANY_ID's x all quarterly END_DATEs? If so, you can get a performance increase by pre-filtering  `table_a` for dates `.between(-30, 0)` (like @sztal's solution), grouping by COMPANY_ID, and summing. You can always subset to only keep the COMPANY_IDs you want. (How many distinct COMPANY_IDs x how many  END_DATEs are there in `table_b`?)

Comment: the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69195082/7175713) is quite efficient, with a simple algorithm

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Well, I can think of a few ways:

1. essentially blow up the dataframe by **just merging on the exact field (`company`)... then filter on the 30-day windows after the merge.**

- should be fast but could use lots of memory

2. **Move the merging and filtering on the 30-day window into a `groupby()`**.

- results in a merge for each group, so slower but should use less memory

**Option #1**

Suppose your data looks like the following (I expanded your sample data):

```
print df

    company       date  measure
0         0 2010-01-01       10
1         0 2010-01-15       10
2         0 2010-02-01       10
3         0 2010-02-15       10
4         0 2010-03-01       10
5         0 2010-03-15       10
6         0 2010-04-01       10
7         1 2010-03-01        5
8         1 2010-03-15        5
9         1 2010-04-01        5
10        1 2010-04-15        5
11        1 2010-05-01        5
12        1 2010-05-15        5

print windows

   company   end_date
0        0 2010-02-01
1        0 2010-03-15
2        1 2010-04-01
3        1 2010-05-15
```

Create a beginning date for the 30 day windows:

```
windows['beg_date'] = (windows['end_date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]') -
                       np.timedelta64(30,'D'))
print windows

   company   end_date   beg_date
0        0 2010-02-01 2010-01-02
1        0 2010-03-15 2010-02-13
2        1 2010-04-01 2010-03-02
3        1 2010-05-15 2010-04-15
```

Now do a merge and then select based on if `date` falls within `beg_date` and `end_date`:

```
df = df.merge(windows,on='company',how='left')
df = df[(df.date >= df.beg_date) & (df.date <= df.end_date)]
print df

    company       date  measure   end_date   beg_date
2         0 2010-01-15       10 2010-02-01 2010-01-02
4         0 2010-02-01       10 2010-02-01 2010-01-02
7         0 2010-02-15       10 2010-03-15 2010-02-13
9         0 2010-03-01       10 2010-03-15 2010-02-13
11        0 2010-03-15       10 2010-03-15 2010-02-13
16        1 2010-03-15        5 2010-04-01 2010-03-02
18        1 2010-04-01        5 2010-04-01 2010-03-02
21        1 2010-04-15        5 2010-05-15 2010-04-15
23        1 2010-05-01        5 2010-05-15 2010-04-15
25        1 2010-05-15        5 2010-05-15 2010-04-15
```

You can compute the 30 day window sums by grouping on `company` and `end_date`:

```
print df.groupby(['company','end_date']).sum()

                    measure
company end_date           
0       2010-02-01       20
        2010-03-15       30
1       2010-04-01       10
        2010-05-15       15
```

**Option #2** Move all merging into a groupby. This should be better on memory but I would think much slower:

```
windows['beg_date'] = (windows['end_date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]') -
                       np.timedelta64(30,'D'))

def cond_merge(g,windows):
    g = g.merge(windows,on='company',how='left')
    g = g[(g.date >= g.beg_date) & (g.date <= g.end_date)]
    return g.groupby('end_date')['measure'].sum()

print df.groupby('company').apply(cond_merge,windows)

company  end_date  
0        2010-02-01    20
         2010-03-15    30
1        2010-04-01    10
         2010-05-15    15
```

**Another option** Now if your windows never overlap (like in the example data), you could do something like the following as an alternative that doesn't blow up a dataframe but is pretty fast:

```
windows['date'] = windows['end_date']

df = df.merge(windows,on=['company','date'],how='outer')
print df

    company       date  measure   end_date
0         0 2010-01-01       10        NaT
1         0 2010-01-15       10        NaT
2         0 2010-02-01       10 2010-02-01
3         0 2010-02-15       10        NaT
4         0 2010-03-01       10        NaT
5         0 2010-03-15       10 2010-03-15
6         0 2010-04-01       10        NaT
7         1 2010-03-01        5        NaT
8         1 2010-03-15        5        NaT
9         1 2010-04-01        5 2010-04-01
10        1 2010-04-15        5        NaT
11        1 2010-05-01        5        NaT
12        1 2010-05-15        5 2010-05-15
```

This merge essentially inserts your window end dates into the dataframe and then backfilling the end dates (by group) will give you a structure to easily create you summation windows:

```
df['end_date'] = df.groupby('company')['end_date'].apply(lambda x: x.bfill())

print df

    company       date  measure   end_date
0         0 2010-01-01       10 2010-02-01
1         0 2010-01-15       10 2010-02-01
2         0 2010-02-01       10 2010-02-01
3         0 2010-02-15       10 2010-03-15
4         0 2010-03-01       10 2010-03-15
5         0 2010-03-15       10 2010-03-15
6         0 2010-04-01       10        NaT
7         1 2010-03-01        5 2010-04-01
8         1 2010-03-15        5 2010-04-01
9         1 2010-04-01        5 2010-04-01
10        1 2010-04-15        5 2010-05-15
11        1 2010-05-01        5 2010-05-15
12        1 2010-05-15        5 2010-05-15

df = df[df.end_date.notnull()]
df['beg_date'] = (df['end_date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]') -
                   np.timedelta64(30,'D'))

print df

   company       date  measure   end_date   beg_date
0         0 2010-01-01       10 2010-02-01 2010-01-02
1         0 2010-01-15       10 2010-02-01 2010-01-02
2         0 2010-02-01       10 2010-02-01 2010-01-02
3         0 2010-02-15       10 2010-03-15 2010-02-13
4         0 2010-03-01       10 2010-03-15 2010-02-13
5         0 2010-03-15       10 2010-03-15 2010-02-13
7         1 2010-03-01        5 2010-04-01 2010-03-02
8         1 2010-03-15        5 2010-04-01 2010-03-02
9         1 2010-04-01        5 2010-04-01 2010-03-02
10        1 2010-04-15        5 2010-05-15 2010-04-15
11        1 2010-05-01        5 2010-05-15 2010-04-15
12        1 2010-05-15        5 2010-05-15 2010-04-15

df = df[(df.date >= df.beg_date) & (df.date <= df.end_date)]
print df.groupby(['company','end_date']).sum()

                    measure
company end_date           
0       2010-02-01       20
        2010-03-15       30
1       2010-04-01       10
        2010-05-15       15
```

Another alternative is to resample your first dataframe to daily data and then compute rolling_sums with a 30 day window; and select the dates at the end that you are interested in. This could be quite memory intensive too.

Comment: +1 for showing two strategies and their strengths/weaknesses.

Answer (score 11):

There is a very easy, and practical (or maybe the only direct way) to do conditional join in pandas. Since there is no direct way to do conditional join in pandas, you will need an additional library, and that is, `pandasql`

Install the library `pandasql` from pip using the command `pip install pandasql`. This library allows you to manipulate the pandas dataframes using the SQL queries.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasql import sqldf

df = pd.read_excel(r'play_data.xlsx')
df

    id    Name  Amount
0   A001    A   100
1   A002    B   110
2   A003    C   120
3   A005    D   150
```

Now let's just do a conditional join to compare the Amount of the IDs

```
# Make your pysqldf object:
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

# Write your query in SQL syntax, here you can use df as a normal SQL table
cond_join= '''
    select 
        df_left.*,
        df_right.*
    from df as df_left
    join df as df_right
    on
        df_left.[Amount] > (df_right.[Amount]+10)

'''

# Now, get your queries results as dataframe using the sqldf object that you created
pysqldf(cond_join)

    id  Name    Amount  id    Name  Amount
0   A003    C   120    A001   A   100
1   A005    D   150    A001   A   100
2   A005    D   150    A002   B   110
3   A005    D   150    A003   C   120
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for the answer!!  PS - i was calling this within a function and utilized `locals()` instead of `globals()`.  
        `cond_join = """
            select df_left.*, df_right.*
            from t_p as df_left
            join t_s as df_right on df_left.short_key = df_right.short_key
        """`
        `combo = sqldf(cond_join, locals())`

Comment: Anyhbody knows what pandas actually does under the hood. I guess it will follow one of the above stated strategies.

Comment: Any benchmarking of this in terms of speed/perf wise?

Comment: pandasql is not maintained any more. some people have suggested DuckDB as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [karl D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3435183/karl-d)'s data.

[conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) offers a way to deal with non-equi joins efficiently:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df
.conditional_join(
    windows, # series or dataframe to join to
    # variable arguments
    # left column, right column, join operator
    ('company', 'company', '=='), 
    ('date', 'beg_date', '>='), 
    ('date', 'end_date', '<='), 
    # for more performance, depending on the data size
    # you can turn on use_numba
    use_numba = False,
    # filter for specific columns, if required
    df_columns=['company', 'measure'],
    right_columns='end_date')
.groupby(['company', 'end_date'])
.sum()
)
                    measure
company end_date           
0       2010-02-01       20
        2010-03-15       30
1       2010-04-01       10
        2010-05-15       15
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late for the party but here are two solutions. The first one is rather simple but not very general, while the second one should be more universal. In what follows I assume that `table_a` and `table_b` objects are already defined as in the original question.

### Solution 1

This one is simple. Here we just do a left join and append `END_DATE` values to `table_a` and then filter out the rows we are not interested in. So the memory overhead here is `size of table_a * number of unique END_DATE values per COMPANY in table_b`.

```py
table_c = table_a.merge(table_b, left_on="COMPANY_ID", right_on="COMPANY")
table_c[(table_c["DATE"] - table_c["END_DATE"]).dt.days.between(-30, 0)] \
    .groupby(["COMPANY", "END_DATE"])["MEASURE"].sum()

## OUTPUT:
COMPANY  END_DATE  
1        2010-03-01    310
         2010-06-02    310
2        2010-03-01    310
         2010-06-02    310
Name: MEASURE, dtype: int64
```

This is quite fast, but could blow up the size of `table_a` significantly if `table_b` contained many values.

### Solution 2

This one is a bit smarter and operates row-by-row, where to each row in `table_b` we explicitly map only the relevant subset of `table_a`. Thus, we get only the data we need, so there is no memory overhead (beyond the memory needed to represent the raw records over which we want to sum).

```py
table_b.groupby(["COMPANY", "END_DATE"]) \
    .apply(lambda g: table_a[
        (table_a["COMPANY_ID"] == g["COMPANY"].iloc[0]) & \
        ((table_a["DATE"] - g["END_DATE"].iloc[0]).dt.days.between(-30, 0))
    ]["MEASURE"].sum())

## OUTPUT:
COMPANY  END_DATE  
1        2010-03-01    310
         2010-06-02    310
2        2010-03-01    310
         2010-06-02    310
dtype: int64
```

Note that in this case for each inequality we use only the relevant subsets of `table_a`, which will be much more memory efficient. The price is that this soution seems to be about 2-3 times slower (but in general still relatively fast; ~2-3ms runtime on your data).

Comment: Can you briefly summarize in words each approach? Also, isn't `.values[0]` just an obfuscation for `.head(1)`?

Comment: Sure, I added the descriptions in words. And to some extent yes, `.values[0]` is the same thing as `.head(1)`. The advantage (but rather not really important) is that it avoids an extra method call. And as whether this is an "obfuscation" or not this is largely a matter of taste. For me it does not look like an obfuscation at all, since using Numpy arrays behind Pandas objects seems quite a natural thing to do.

Comment: pandas has been [deprecating using the `.values` accessor since 2019](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#accessing-the-values-in-a-series-or-index). It is not a matter of taste. You should use `.head(1)`. See [this mention in python chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/6?m=51502228#51502228)

Comment: Ah, I did not know that, so thanks a lot! I changed `.values[0]` to `.iloc[0]` in the examples.