# Can one use comparisons to merge two pandas data-frames?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

With the following command:

```
pandas.merge(df_1, df_2, left_on=['date'], right_on=['from_date'])
```

I combine two rows from two tables if a value in `date`-column of the first table is equal to the value in the `from_date`-column of the second table.

Now I would like to make it slightly more complex. I need to combine a row from the first table with a row from the second table if the value in the `date` column of the first table is equal or lager than a value of the `from_date`-column of the second table and smaller than value in the `upto_date`-column of the second column.

In SQL one would use something like that:

```
select
    *
from
    table_1
join
    table_2
on
    table_1.date >= table_2.from_date
    and
    table_1.date <  table_2.upto_date
```

Is it possible to do it in pandas.

Comment: Could you provide a short sample of your df1 and df2?

Comment: Since the values you're joining on are no longer unique, you may not have the merge working as you expect. Perhaps look into .join, or .concat if you're looking to simply add the two tables together

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508351/how-to-do-a-conditional-join-in-python-pandas. There is a proposed issue regarding Conditional Join for Pandas DataFrame (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7480)

Comment: Wondering if a non-SQL solution would be easier (ie: parse + merge in python).

Answer (score 2):

`pandasql` is a pretty useful tool for querying pandas DataFrames using SQLite query syntax.

**Resources**

- [pandasql - PyPI Documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandasql)
- [yhat/pandasql - Source on Github](https://github.com/yhat/pandasql)
- [Blog post with more examples](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/pandasql-sql-for-pandas-dataframes.html)

  `pip install -U pandasql`

Here's an example similar to the one you describe.

**Imports**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.parsers import StringIO
from pandasql import sqldf

# helper func useful for saving keystrokes
# when running multiple queries
def dbGetQuery(q):
    return sqldf(q, globals())
```

**Fake some data**

```
sample_a = """timepoint,measure
2014-01-01 00:00:00,78
2014-01-03 00:00:00,5
2014-01-04 00:00:00,73
2014-01-05 00:00:00,40
2014-01-06 00:00:00,45
2014-01-08 00:00:00,2
2014-01-09 00:00:00,96
2014-01-10 00:00:00,82
2014-01-11 00:00:00,61
2014-01-12 00:00:00,68
2014-01-13 00:00:00,8
2014-01-14 00:00:00,94
2014-01-15 00:00:00,16
2014-01-16 00:00:00,31
2014-01-17 00:00:00,10
2014-01-18 00:00:00,34
2014-01-19 00:00:00,27
2014-01-20 00:00:00,75
2014-01-21 00:00:00,49
2014-01-23 00:00:00,28
2014-01-24 00:00:00,91
2014-01-25 00:00:00,88
2014-01-27 00:00:00,98
2014-01-28 00:00:00,39
2014-01-29 00:00:00,90
2014-01-30 00:00:00,63
2014-01-31 00:00:00,77
"""

sample_b = """from_date,to_date,measure
2014-01-02 00:00:00,2014-01-06 00:00:00,89
2014-01-03 00:00:00,2014-01-07 00:00:00,80
2014-01-04 00:00:00,2014-01-05 00:00:00,44
2014-01-05 00:00:00,2014-01-12 00:00:00,68
2014-01-06 00:00:00,2014-01-11 00:00:00,62
2014-01-07 00:00:00,2014-01-14 00:00:00,5
2014-01-08 00:00:00,2014-01-09 00:00:00,23
"""
```

**Read datasets to create 2 DataFrames**

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(sample_a), parse_dates=['timepoint'])
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(sample_b), parse_dates=['from_date', 'to_date'])
```

**Write a SQL query**

Note that this one uses the SQLite `BETWEEN` operator. You can also swap that out and use something like `ON timepoint >= from_date AND timepoint < to_date` if you prefer.

```
query = """
SELECT
    DATE(df1.timepoint) AS timepoint
    , DATE(df2.from_date) AS start
    , DATE(df2.to_date) AS end
    , df1.measure AS measure_a
    , df2.measure AS measure_b
FROM
    df1 
INNER JOIN df2
    ON df1.timepoint BETWEEN 
        df2.from_date AND df2.to_date
ORDER BY
    df1.timepoint;
"""
```

**Run the query using the helper func**

```
df3 = dbGetQuery(query)

df3
     timepoint       start         end  measure_a  measure_b
0   2014-01-03  2014-01-02  2014-01-06          5         89
1   2014-01-03  2014-01-03  2014-01-07          5         80
2   2014-01-04  2014-01-02  2014-01-06         73         89
3   2014-01-04  2014-01-03  2014-01-07         73         80
4   2014-01-04  2014-01-04  2014-01-05         73         44
5   2014-01-05  2014-01-02  2014-01-06         40         89
6   2014-01-05  2014-01-03  2014-01-07         40         80
7   2014-01-05  2014-01-04  2014-01-05         40         44
8   2014-01-05  2014-01-05  2014-01-12         40         68
9   2014-01-06  2014-01-02  2014-01-06         45         89
10  2014-01-06  2014-01-03  2014-01-07         45         80
11  2014-01-06  2014-01-05  2014-01-12         45         68
12  2014-01-06  2014-01-06  2014-01-11         45         62
13  2014-01-08  2014-01-05  2014-01-12          2         68
14  2014-01-08  2014-01-06  2014-01-11          2         62
15  2014-01-08  2014-01-07  2014-01-14          2          5
16  2014-01-08  2014-01-08  2014-01-09          2         23
17  2014-01-09  2014-01-05  2014-01-12         96         68
18  2014-01-09  2014-01-06  2014-01-11         96         62
19  2014-01-09  2014-01-07  2014-01-14         96          5
20  2014-01-09  2014-01-08  2014-01-09         96         23
21  2014-01-10  2014-01-05  2014-01-12         82         68
22  2014-01-10  2014-01-06  2014-01-11         82         62
23  2014-01-10  2014-01-07  2014-01-14         82          5
24  2014-01-11  2014-01-05  2014-01-12         61         68
25  2014-01-11  2014-01-06  2014-01-11         61         62
26  2014-01-11  2014-01-07  2014-01-14         61          5
27  2014-01-12  2014-01-05  2014-01-12         68         68
28  2014-01-12  2014-01-07  2014-01-14         68          5
29  2014-01-13  2014-01-07  2014-01-14          8          5
30  2014-01-14  2014-01-07  2014-01-14         94          5
```

Comment: Python tells me pandasql has no attirbute 'dbGetQuery'. I also can't find any information online on this module. Does this code really work?

Comment: I defined dbGetQuery at the top of my answer. It's just a helper function I always write.

Answer (score 0):

[conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) covers inequality joins efficiently :

Using [@hernamesbarbara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359786/hernamesbarbara)'s fake data:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df1.conditional_join(
         df2, 
         ('timepoint', 'from_date', '>='), 
         ('timepoint', 'to_date', '<='))
)
 
         left              right                   
    timepoint measure  from_date    to_date measure
0  2014-01-03       5 2014-01-02 2014-01-06      89
1  2014-01-03       5 2014-01-03 2014-01-07      80
2  2014-01-04      73 2014-01-02 2014-01-06      89
3  2014-01-04      73 2014-01-03 2014-01-07      80
4  2014-01-04      73 2014-01-04 2014-01-05      44
5  2014-01-05      40 2014-01-02 2014-01-06      89
6  2014-01-05      40 2014-01-03 2014-01-07      80
7  2014-01-05      40 2014-01-04 2014-01-05      44
8  2014-01-05      40 2014-01-05 2014-01-12      68
9  2014-01-06      45 2014-01-02 2014-01-06      89
10 2014-01-06      45 2014-01-03 2014-01-07      80
11 2014-01-06      45 2014-01-05 2014-01-12      68
12 2014-01-06      45 2014-01-06 2014-01-11      62
13 2014-01-08       2 2014-01-05 2014-01-12      68
14 2014-01-08       2 2014-01-06 2014-01-11      62
15 2014-01-08       2 2014-01-07 2014-01-14       5
16 2014-01-08       2 2014-01-08 2014-01-09      23
17 2014-01-09      96 2014-01-05 2014-01-12      68
18 2014-01-09      96 2014-01-06 2014-01-11      62
19 2014-01-09      96 2014-01-07 2014-01-14       5
20 2014-01-09      96 2014-01-08 2014-01-09      23
21 2014-01-10      82 2014-01-05 2014-01-12      68
22 2014-01-10      82 2014-01-06 2014-01-11      62
23 2014-01-10      82 2014-01-07 2014-01-14       5
24 2014-01-11      61 2014-01-05 2014-01-12      68
25 2014-01-11      61 2014-01-06 2014-01-11      62
26 2014-01-11      61 2014-01-07 2014-01-14       5
27 2014-01-12      68 2014-01-05 2014-01-12      68
28 2014-01-12      68 2014-01-07 2014-01-14       5
29 2014-01-13       8 2014-01-07 2014-01-14       5
30 2014-01-14      94 2014-01-07 2014-01-14       5
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I think. However, I am not sure if it is elegant and optimal:

```
df_1['A'] = 'A'
df_2['A'] = 'A'
df = pandas.merge(df_1, df_2, on=['A'])
df = df[(df['date'] >= df['from']) & (df['date'] < df['upto'])]
del df['A']
```

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>