# intersection 2 pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, intersection

in my problem I have 2 dataframes `mydataframe1` and `mydataframe2` as below.

```
mydataframe1
Out[13]:
  Start   End       Remove     
  50      60        1  
  61      105       0  
  106     150       1  
  151     160       0  
  161     180       1  
  181     200       0  
  201     400       1  


mydataframe2
Out[14]: 
    Start   End  
    55      100
    105     140
    151     154
    155     185
    220     240
```

From `mydataframe2` I would like to remove the rows for which the interval Start-End are contained (also partially) in any of the `"Remove"`=1 intervals in `mydataframe1`. In other words there should not be any itnersection between the intervals of `mydataframe2` and each of the intervals in `mydataframe1`

in this case mydataframe2 becomes

```
mydataframe2
Out[15]: 
    Start   End  
    151     154
```

Comment: Shouldn't `105     140` also remain?

Comment: mmm no because we have the 3rd row of mydataframe1 106     150       1  that overlaps with that interval

Comment: so you don't really need the remove=0 rows, right?  The default behavior is not to remove unless there's a range with remove=1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a conditional join in python Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508351/how-to-do-a-conditional-join-in-python-pandas)

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 yes, I don't need the remove=0, only the remove=1 are useful..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `pd.IntervalIndex` for intersections

Get rows to be removed

```
In [313]: dfr = df1.query('Remove == 1')
```

Construct IntervalIndex from to be removed ranges

```
In [314]: s1 = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(dfr.Start, dfr.End, 'both')
```

Construct IntervalIndex from to be tested

```
In [315]: s2 = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2.Start, df2.End, 'both')
```

Select rows of s2 which are not in s1 ranges

```
In [316]: df2.loc[[x not in s1 for x in s2]]
Out[316]:
   Start  End
2    151  154
```

---

Details

```
In [320]: df1
Out[320]:
   Start  End  Remove
0     50   60       1
1     61  105       0
2    106  150       1
3    151  160       0
4    161  180       1
5    181  200       0
6    201  400       1

In [321]: df2
Out[321]:
   Start  End
0     55  100
1    105  140
2    151  154
3    155  185
4    220  240

In [322]: dfr
Out[322]:
   Start  End  Remove
0     50   60       1
2    106  150       1
4    161  180       1
6    201  400       1
```

IntervalIndex details

```
In [323]: s1
Out[323]:
IntervalIndex([[50, 60], [106, 150], [161, 180], [201, 400]]
              closed='both',
              dtype='interval[int64]')

In [324]: s2
Out[324]:
IntervalIndex([[55, 100], [105, 140], [151, 154], [155, 185], [220, 240]]
              closed='both',
              dtype='interval[int64]')

In [326]: [x not in s1 for x in s2]
Out[326]: [False, False, True, False, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [Medial- or length-oriented tree: Overlap test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Overlap_test):

```
In [143]: d1 = d1.assign(s=d1.Start+d1.End, d=d1.End-d1.Start)

In [144]: d2 = d2.assign(s=d2.Start+d2.End, d=d2.End-d2.Start)

In [145]: d1
Out[145]:
   Start  End  Remove    d    s
0     50   60       1   10  110
1     61  105       0   44  166
2    106  150       1   44  256
3    151  160       0    9  311
4    161  180       1   19  341
5    181  200       0   19  381
6    201  400       1  199  601

In [146]: d2
Out[146]:
   Start  End   d    s
0     55  100  45  155
1    105  140  35  245
2    151  154   3  305
3    155  185  30  340
4    220  240  20  460
```

now we can check for overlapping intervals and filter:

```
In [148]: d2[~d2[['s','d']]\
     ...:       .apply(lambda x: ((d1.loc[d1.Remove==1, 's'] - x.s).abs() <
     ...:                         d1.loc[d1.Remove==1, 'd'] +x.d).any(),
     ...:              axis=1)]\
     ...:   .drop(['s','d'], 1)
     ...:
Out[148]:
   Start  End
2    151  154
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should work:

```
mydataframe2[mydataframe2.Start.isin(mydataframe1[mydataframe1.Remove != 0].Start)]
```

Breaking it down:

```
# This filter will remove anything which has Remove not 0
filter_non_remove = mydataframe1.Remove != 0

# This provides a valid Sequence of Start values
valid_starts = mydataframe1[mydataframe1.Remove != 0].Start

# Another filter, that checks whether the Start 
# value is in the valid_starts Sequence
is_df2_valid = mydataframe2.Start.isin(valid_starts)

# Final applied filter
output = mydataframe2[is_df2_valid]
```

Comment: I don't think this works, but feel free to show output.  It's just checking for whether start value is in the sequence, but it could be contained within a range, and that wouldn't be checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the unique range values from the columns marked `Remove` then evaluate the `Start` and `End` dates contained in `mydataframe2` are not in any of the range values.  The first part will define all unique values falling with the Start/End values were Remove = 1.

```
start_end_remove = mydataframe1[mydataframe1['Remove'] == 1][['Start', 'End']].as_matrix()
remove_ranges = set([])
for x in start_end_remove:
    remove_ranges.update(np.arange(x[0], x[1] + 1))
```

Next you can evaluate `mydataframe2` against the unique set of range values.  If the Start/End values of `mydataframe2` are in the range of values they are removed from the dataframe by flagging whether they should be removed in a new columns.  A function is defined to see if there is overlap between any of the ranges, then that function is applied to each row in `mydataframe2` and remove the rows where the ranges do overlap.

```
def evaluate_in_range(x, remove_ranges):
    s = x[0]
    e = x[1]
    eval_range = set(np.arange(s, e + 1))
    if len(eval_range.intersection(remove_ranges)) > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

mydataframe2['Remove'] = mydataframe2[['Start', 'End']].apply(lambda x: evaluate_in_range(x, remove_ranges), axis=1)
mydataframe2.drop(mydataframe2[mydataframe2['Remove'] == 1].index, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
mydataframe1['key']=1
mydataframe2['key']=1

df3 = mydataframe2.merge(mydataframe1, on="key")

df3['s_gt_s'] = df3.Start_y > df3.Start_x
df3['s_lt_e'] = df3.Start_y < df3.End_x
df3['e_gt_s'] = df3.End_y > df3.Start_x
df3['e_lt_e'] = df3.End_y < df3.End_x

df3['s_in'] = df3.s_gt_s & df3.s_lt_e
df3['e_in'] = df3.e_gt_s & df3.e_lt_e

df3['overlaps'] = df3.s_in | df3.e_in

my_new_dataframe = df3[df3.overlaps & df3.Remove==1][['End_x','Start_x']].drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Shouldn't `df3['s_lt_e'] = df3.Start_y > df3.End_x` be `df3['s_gt_e'] = df3.Start_y > df3.End_x`?

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join)

Note that this uses the [dev version](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor), which is optimised:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
# dev version, optimised
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git

(df2
.conditional_join(
    df1.loc[df1.Remove==1], 
    ('Start', 'End', '<='), 
    ('End', 'Start', '>='), 
    how='left', 
    right_columns='Remove')
.loc[lambda df: df.Remove.isna(), df2.columns]
) 
   Start  End
2    151  154
```