# SQL style conditional joins in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dfs which look like this

df1:

```
ID  year  notes  score
12  2015  text   15.1
54  2014  text   18.4
```

df2:

```
id_num  year  score
12      2015  15.1
12      2014  12.9
54      2014  18.4
```

I'm trying to create a new df with all the data from df1 and only the score column from df where df1.year = df2.year+1.  Like this:

```
ID  year   notes  score  prior_yr_score
12  2015   text   15.1   12.9
```

I'm reading through the pandas documentation, but am not finding a way to do this type of conditional joining. In sql I could just do

```
select a.*, b.score as prior_yr_score
from df1 as a left join df2 as b
on a.ID=b.id_num and a.year = b.year+1
```

Whereas in python I'm stuck at

```
merged=pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left',left_on='ID',right_on='id_num')
```

How can I do this in a single statement (`pd.merge` or otherwise)?

edit: I've read through some other posts and documentation about sql style joins in python, but have not been able to find a clear answer.  For example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508351/how-to-do-a-conditional-join-in-python-pandas) looks similar but in the answers it seems like the OP is actually trying to calculate aggregate measures by group with conditions as opposed to joining 2 dfs with conditions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a conditional join in python Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508351/how-to-do-a-conditional-join-in-python-pandas)

Comment: @AndrewL - that post seems to be more about calculating an aggregate measure for a group.  Though maybe I'm misreading the answers to that post

Answer (score 1):

```
In [92]: d1.merge(d2.assign(year=d2.year+1, prior_yr_score=d2.score).drop('score',1), left_on=['ID','year'], right_on=['id_num','year'])
Out[92]:
   ID  year notes  score  id_num  prior_yr_score
0  12  2015  text   15.1      12            12.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add a column to your df2 that does the year+1 calculation, then merge on that new column instead?

Comment: Sure - but I'm looking for a way to do this in a single statement.