# How to a conditional join(like SQL where join) of Dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes like below

**df1**

```
visit_counts SG_lat   SG_long
0   3222.0  33.13623    -91.942026
1   6243.0  33.241981   -92.668384
2   5225.0  33.27683    -93.212498
3   6107.0  33.461784   -94.039191
4   3712.0  33.567683   -92.83685799999999
```

**df2**

```
num_transactions lat_dgr    long_dgr
0   45433   35.293364   -93.716224
1   41172   35.293364   -93.716224
2   41909   35.293364   -93.716224
3   37979   35.293364   -93.716224
4   43546   35.293364   -93.716224
```

**I want to inner join these dataframes if the geo distance between two coordinates is less than 100m
like below pseudo code**
i.e

```
## pseudo code
coords_1 = (df1.SG_lat, df1.SG_long)
coords_2 = (df2.lat_dgr, df2.long_dgr)
geopy.distance.vincenty(coords_1, coords_2).m < 100
```

In SQL we can do this with where condition like below

```
ST_DISTANCE(ST_GEOGPOINT(long_dgr,lat_dgr), ST_GEOGPOINT( sg_long,sg_lat)) <= 100
```

pandas merge function doesn't allow for where condition. Is there any other way to join these two dataframes. I don't have any other key columns to join and then filter using **loc**.

Comment: do you want to compute all possible distances, or just those of common row/index?

Comment: @anon01 i want to compute all possible distances and then join values if distance is less than 100 i.e. i am looking for an inner join where distance < 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to compute the distance all row combinations across tables, you can: 1) create a cartesian product of the tables, 2) compute the distance 3) filter on your threshold.  This is memory inefficient as you are expanding out all row combinations, but at least straightforward to compute:

```py
import pandas as pd
from geopy.distance import geodesic

# create a dummy key to join all rows from df1 to df2:
df1["dummy_key"] = 0
df2["dummy_key"] = 0

# create cartesian product table
df3 = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on="dummy_key").drop(columns=["dummy_key"])

# apply geodesic (newer version of geopy.distance.vincenty) to get the distance in meters for each row
dist = df3.apply(lambda row: geodesic((row["SG_lat"], row["SG_long"]), (row["lat_dgr"], row["long_dgr"])).m, axis=1) 

# filter for rows that you desire:
df3 = df3[dist < 100]
```

Comment: this would compute the distance for rows of common index, but actually i am combining based on distance as to find the common rows.The table has some other columns and latitude, longitude are not sorted in any order. So, i am looking for an inner join based on distance.

Comment: @krishnakoti makes sense, I'll update.  How big are your tables, how much memory do  you have?

Comment: the tables are of medium size and both of them contains around 2k rows.

Comment: @krishnakoti revised answer above.  Here is a simillar question/solution that discusses some other approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508351/how-to-do-a-conditional-join-in-python-pandas

Comment: FWIW, it looks like this has been recently discussed in conversations about the pandas API: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7480