# pandas dataframe merge expression using a less-than operator?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I was trying to **merge two dataframes using a less-than operator**. But I ended up using `pandasql`.

Is it possible to do the same query below using pandas functions?
(Records may be duplicated, but that is fine as I'm looking for something similar to cumulative total later)

```
sql = '''select A.Name,A.Code,B.edate from df1 A
        inner join df2 B on A.Name = B.Name
        and A.Code=B.Code
        where A.edate < B.edate '''

df4 = sqldf(sql)
```

[The suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508351/how-to-do-workaround-a-conditional-join-in-python-pandas) seems similar but couldn't get the result expected. Also the answer below looks very crisp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a conditional join in python Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508351/how-to-do-a-conditional-join-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['Name','Code']).query('edate_x < edate_y')[['Name','Code','edate_y']]
```

Comment: jezrael, could you add this method to [How to do/workaround a conditional join in python Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508351/how-to-do-workaround-a-conditional-join-in-python-pandas)

Comment: @smci - I think it is something else, so not dupe, only similar.

Comment: `df.query` is very useful but under-used. +1

Comment: rael, perhaps, but that other question could sorely use your mention of `df.query()`, so I recommend you add it there too.

Comment: I faced a memory error though with large dataset while merging. Though it won't be an issue for small datasets. My actual datasets are 5M and 2M records. and it gave `MemoryError` while `sqldf` worked without error,

Comment: @sjd - Unfortunately pandas working not so nice like sql libs :(

Comment: This works well for me. If people are facing a memory error, I would suggest subsetting your data (ie if working by user, do chunks of 500 users etc). Excellent suggestion I was stuck.