# Conditional groupby on dates using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm in a bit of a pickle. I've been working on a problem all day without seeing any real results. I'm working in Python and using Pandas for handling data.

What I'm trying to achieve is based on the customers previous interactions to sum each type of interaction. The timestamp of the interaction should be less than the timestamp of the survey. Ideally, I would like to sum the interactions for the customer during some period - like less than e.g. 5 years.

The first dataframe contains a customer ID, segmentation of that customer during in that survey e.g. 1 being "happy", 2 being "sad" and a timestamp for the time of the recorded segment or time of that survey.

```
import pandas as pd

#Generic example
customers = pd.DataFrame({"customerID":[1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4],"customerSeg":[1,2,2,1,2,3,3,3],"timestamp":['1999-01-01','2000-01-01','2000-06-01','2001-01-01','2003-01-01','1999-01-01','2005-01-01','2008-01-01']})

customers
```

Which yields something like:

| customerID | customerSeg | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1999-01-01 |
| 1 | 1 | 2000-01-01 |
| 1 | 1 | 2000-06-01 |
| 2 | 2 | 2001-01-01 |
| 2 | 2 | 2003-01-01 |
| 3 | 3 | 1999-01-01 |
| 4 | 4 | 2005-01-01 |
| 4 | 4 | 2008-01-01 |

The other dataframe contains interactions with that customer eg. at service and a phonecall.

```
interactions = pd.DataFrame({"customerID":[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,4,4],"timestamp":['1999-07-01','1999-11-01','2000-03-01','2001-04-01','2000-12-01','2002-01-01','2004-03-01','2004-05-01','2000-01-01','2004-01-01','2009-01-01'],"service":[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1],"phonecall":[0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1]})
interactions
```

Output:

| customerID | timestamp | service | phonecall |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1999-07-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1999-11-01 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2000-03-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2001-04-01 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2000-12-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2002-01-01 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2004-03-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2004-05-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2000-01-01 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 2004-01-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 2009-01-01 | 1 | 1 |

Result for all previous interactions (ideally, I would like only the last 5 years):

| customerID | customerSeg | timestamp | service | phonecall |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1999-01-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2000-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2000-06-01 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2001-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2003-01-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 1999-01-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 2005-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 2008-01-01 | 1 | 1 |

I've tried almost everything, I could come up with. So, I would really appreciate some inputs. I'm pretty much confined to using Pandas and Python, since it's the language, I'm most familiar with, but also because I need to read a csv file of the customer segmentation.

Comment: Is there a limit for the time passed between the interaction and the survey, beyond which the survey results are not related anymore to the last interaction?

Comment: And is there a limit for the amount of interactions that a single survey should match?

Comment: Possibly related, according to [Aakash Parsi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12012766/aakash-parsi): [How to do/workaround a conditional join in python Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23508351/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need several steps for transforming your data.

First of all, we convert the `timestamp` columns in both dataframes to `datetime`, so we can calculate the desired interval and do the comparisons:

```
customers['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(customers['timestamp'])
interactions['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(interactions['timestamp'])
```

After that, we create a new column that contains that start date (e.g. 5 years before the timestamp):

```
customers['start_date'] = customers['timestamp'] - pd.DateOffset(years=5)
```

Now we join the `customers` dataframe with the `interactions` dataframe on the `customerID`:

```
result = customers.merge(interactions, on='customerID', how='outer')
```

This yields

```
    customerID  customerSeg timestamp_x start_date timestamp_y  service  phonecall
0            1            1  1999-01-01 1994-01-01  1999-07-01      1.0        0.0
1            1            1  1999-01-01 1994-01-01  1999-11-01      0.0        1.0
2            1            1  1999-01-01 1994-01-01  2000-03-01      1.0        1.0
3            1            1  1999-01-01 1994-01-01  2001-04-01      0.0        1.0
4            1            2  2000-01-01 1995-01-01  1999-07-01      1.0        0.0
5            1            2  2000-01-01 1995-01-01  1999-11-01      0.0        1.0
6            1            2  2000-01-01 1995-01-01  2000-03-01      1.0        1.0
7            1            2  2000-01-01 1995-01-01  2001-04-01      0.0        1.0
...
```

Now here is how the condition is evaluated - what we want is that only those `service` and `phonecall` interactions will be used that are in rows that meet the condition (`timestamp_y` is in the interval between `start_date` and `timestamp_x`), so we replace the others by zero:

```
result['service'] = result.apply(lambda x: x.service if (x.timestamp_y >= x.start_date) and (x.timestamp_y <= x.timestamp_x) else 0, axis=1)
result['phonecall'] = result.apply(lambda x: x.phonecall if (x.timestamp_y >= x.start_date) and (x.timestamp_y <= x.timestamp_x) else 0, axis=1)
```

Finally we group the dataframe, summing up the `service` and `phonecall` interactions:

```
result = result.groupby(['customerID', 'timestamp_x', 'customerSeg'])[['service', 'phonecall']].sum()
```

Result:

```
                                    service  phonecall
customerID timestamp_x customerSeg                    
1          1999-01-01  1                0.0        0.0
           2000-01-01  2                1.0        1.0
           2000-06-01  2                2.0        2.0
2          2001-01-01  1                1.0        1.0
           2003-01-01  2                1.0        2.0
3          1999-01-01  3                0.0        0.0
4          2005-01-01  3                1.0        1.0
           2008-01-01  3                1.0        0.0
```

(Note that your `customerSeg` data in the sample code seems not quite to match the data in the table.)

Comment: Hey Gerd! Thanks! I seems to do the job perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to compute the rows that match the criteria, before grouping and summing:

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import pandas as pd
import janitor

customers['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(customers['timestamp'])
interactions['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(interactions['timestamp'])
customers['start_date'] = customers['timestamp'] - pd.DateOffset(years=5)

(interactions
 .conditional_join(
     customers,
     # column from left, column from right, comparison operator
     ('timestamp', 'timestamp', '<='),
     ('timestamp', 'start_date', '>='),
     ('customerID', 'customerID', '=='),
     how='right')
  # drop irrelevant columns
 .drop(columns=[('left', 'customerID'), 
                ('left', 'timestamp'), 
                ('right', 'start_date')])
  # return to single index
 .droplevel(0,1)
 .groupby(['customerID', 'customerSeg', 'timestamp'])
 .sum()
)

                                   service  phonecall
customerID customerSeg timestamp                     
1          1           1999-01-01      0.0        0.0
           2           2000-01-01      1.0        1.0
                       2000-06-01      2.0        2.0
2          1           2001-01-01      1.0        1.0
           2           2003-01-01      1.0        2.0
3          3           1999-01-01      0.0        0.0
4          3           2005-01-01      1.0        1.0
                       2008-01-01      1.0        0.0
```