# Pandas join by greater than or less than

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables
A) Contains "Entry number" and "Amount"
B) Contains "From Entry number" and "To Entry Number" and "Created Date"

I would then like to join the two, but I don't have a specific join key as table A has specific "Entry number" - for instance "1000", but table B has intervals, for instance "From Entry number" "900" and "To Entry number" "1100". In SQL I would be able to join them as:

```
select * from table A 
left join table B
on a.[Entry number] >= b.[From Entry number] and a.[Entry number] <= b.[To Entry number]
```

But how can I achieve that is Pandas?

Comment: have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508351/how-to-do-workaround-a-conditional-join-in-python-pandas) for possible solutions

Comment: I have looked at that solution, but there you have some common join key, I don't have that is this case.

Comment: Kindly Provide sample dataframe with expected output

Answer (score 1):

Disclamer: This solution could be quite memory-heavy.

I'm using the following two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
dfa = pd.DataFrame({"Entry Number": [1000, 50],
                    "Amount":[4,2]})
dfb = pd.DataFrame({"From Entry Number":[900, 60],
                    "To Entry Number":[1100, 100],
                    "Create Date":["2021-01-01", "2020-01-01"]})
```

dfa:

| Entry Number | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 4 |
| 50 | 2 |

dfb:

| From Entry Number | To Entry Number | Create Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 900 | 1100 | 2021-01-01 |
| 60 | 100 | 2020-01-01 |

First create a Cartesian (cross) Joined dataframe:

`df = dfa.merge(dfb, how = 'cross')`

This creates the following joined dataframe:

| Entry Number | Amount | From Entry Number | To Entry Number | Create Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 4 | 900 | 1100 | 2021-01-01 |
| 1000 | 4 | 60 | 100 | 2020-01-01 |
| 50 | 2 | 900 | 1100 | 2021-01-01 |
| 50 | 2 | 60 | 100 | 2020-01-01 |

Now you can filter the dataframe based on your conditions:

```
df[
    (df["Entry Number"] >= df["From Entry Number"]) &
    (df["Entry Number"] <= df["To Entry Number"])
  ]
```

End result:

| Entry Number | Amount | From Entry Number | To Entry Number | Create Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 4 | 900 | 1100 | 2021-01-01 |

Answer (score 0):

```
 import pandas as pd
 import sqldf 
    
    dfa = pd.DataFrame({"EntryNumber": [1000, 50],
                        "Amount":[4,2]})
    dfb = pd.DataFrame({"FromEntryNumber":[900, 60],
                        "ToEntryNumber":[1100, 100],
                        "CreateDate":["2021-01-01", "2020-01-01"]})
    
    sqldf.run(
        """
            select * 
            from dfa  
            join dfb on dfa.EntryNumber >= dfb.FromEntryNumber and 
            dfa.EntryNumber<=dfb.ToEntryNumber
        """
    )
```

Using sqldf will allow you to use SQL code in python.

Answer (score 0):

pandas `merge_asof` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof)) essentially solves this.

---

### Example:

```py
timestamps_df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'approx_time': pd.to_datetime(['2023-08-09 14:15:00', '2023-07-01 09:55:00', '2023-07-02 15:55:00']),
    'event_id_1': [1, 2, 3],
})

timestamps_df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'approx_time': pd.to_datetime(['2023-08-09 13:59:00', '2023-07-01 10:15:00', '2023-07-02 11:55:00']),
    'event_id_2': [1, 2, 3]
})

pd.merge_asof(
    timestamps_df_1.sort_values(by='approx_time'),
    timestamps_df_2.sort_values(by='approx_time'),
    on='approx_time',
    tolerance=pd.Timedelta('2h'),
    direction='nearest',
)
```

**result**

```
          approx_time  event_id_1  event_id_2
0 2023-07-01 09:55:00           2         2.0
1 2023-07-02 15:55:00           3         NaN
2 2023-08-09 14:15:00           1         1.0
```