# How to join pandas dataframe with multiple columns and conditions like pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have this join in a pyspark script.

```
    d = d.join(p, [
        d.p_hash == p.hash,
        d.dy >= p.mindy,
        d.dy <= p.maxdy,
    ], "left") \
    .drop(p.hash) \
    .drop(p.mindy) \
    .drop(p.maxdy)
```

The variables 'd' and 'p' are spark dataframes.
Is there any way I could do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply do the merge and filter the data frame with your condition, then drop the unwanted columns.

```py
d = d.merge(p, left_on=['p_hash'], right_on=['hash'], how='left')
d = d[(d['dy'] >= d['mindy']) & (d['dy'] <= d['maxdy'])]
d = d.drop(['hash', 'mindy', 'maxdy'], axis=1)
```

Merge on pandas isn't quite like on pyspark, it doesn't have conditional join.

You can also review answers from here: [How to do/workaround a conditional join in python Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508351/how-to-do-workaround-a-conditional-join-in-python-pandas)

Comment: yaaa thanks man. I got so caught up in joins that I ended up forgetting about filters..